# RPi 2 GPIO LED wont turn off!

Tags: gpio, led

I Set up one LED on GPIO port 17 and turned it on with the following code :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(17,True)
```

This code successfully turned on my LED. Now I cant get it off....even if I reboot the RPi 2. Here is the script I have tried running to turn it off :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(17,False)
```

Why cant I get this LED to turn off?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ClPiKcnxirNTZldGdsbmhyc3lWd1k5QnhldklBbFBGMS04/view

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ClPiKcnxirdHZJa05VQ2RaWDR2S29MU1NtQXF1VnhTTWlZ/view

The first image I reversed the LED so you can see the picture better so the led is off.

The second picture I removed the LED.

It was difficult to take a picture with the led on!

Comment: Have you tried using a different pin?

Comment: Which pin are you using?  Could you post a photo of your connections?

Comment: Okay I added some pictures

Comment: I can't access your pictures without a consent process. Can you repost them into the question using the add image tool next to the formatting options?

Comment: Okay I added consent to the images. Try them now.

Comment: Also yes I have tried using different pins

Comment: All of a sudden this seems familiar. Could you take a look [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39737/cant-get-led-to-turn-off) and see if it's useful?

Comment: goobering you got it! Had to switch the cable around and everything worked perfect. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The GPIO Cable was plugged in backwards causing the LED to stay on. You want the GPIO cables lined side to be facing the SD port. Then everything will work!

Thanks to goobering for helping solve this.